# Quarkus: Is there a way to see general VM information with SmallRye Metrics?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

I'm starting with SmallRye Metrics within Quarkus. It would be nice if I could see some general metrics about the running VM, like heap space etc.

I haven't found anything so far. Did I not search hard enough or is this really missing?

Comment: Have a look at Quarkus Micrometer metrics: https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer

Comment: Thanks! Last time I tried, I had some strange Class loading errors, but now that seems to be fixed.

Comment: Does it have the metrics you expect?